# Using logical symbols determine what it means for an object x to be an element of the set ...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

as the title says, I have: $(A \setminus B)\setminus C$. I converted this to: $$(x \in A\ \land \lnot (x \in B)) \land\ \lnot(x\in C) - Definition \ for\ \backslash
\\then:\ (x \in A\ \land x \notin B)\ \land x \notin C\ - De Morgan \\
then: x \in A\ \land\ (x \notin B\ \land\ x \notin\ C)\ - Assosiative \ law \\
and\ ended\ with: x \in A\ \land\ x \notin\ (B\ \land\ C).$$ Am I on the right track or I got lost in the middle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were done at the first step. $$x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C \iff x\in A \land \neg(x\in B)\land \neg(x\in C)$$

From there you go off the rails. First, $\neg(x\in X)$ is equivalent to $x\notin X$ presumably *by definition* of $\notin$, not by De Morgan. So we can immediately rewrite the previous formula as $$x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C \iff x\in A \land x\notin B \land x\notin C$$ but this is mostly done for aesthetic reasons.

Next, $B\land C$ where $B$ and $C$ are sets doesn't make sense unless $\land$ is your notation for $\cap$, i.e. set intersection. Even if it is, this seems to be moving against the goal of the exercise. Finally, even if you don't care about that, it's simply incorrect that $x\notin (B\cap C) \iff x\notin B \land x\notin C$. *Here* De Morgan is relevant. $$x\notin (B\cap C) = \neg(x\in (B\cap C)) \iff \neg(x\in B \land x \in C) \iff \neg(x\in B)\lor \neg(x \in C)$$ where the final $\iff$ is De Morgan's law. If you wanted to, you could say $x\notin (B\cup C)$, i.e. $x$ is not in the union of $B$ and $C$, but, again, this seems to be going against the spirit of the exercise. That said, this would be good for a proof that $(A\setminus B)\setminus C = A \setminus (B\cup C)$.